# SQL - Dividing aggregated fields, very new to SQL

Tags: sql, field, division

I have list of line items from invoices with a field that indicates if a line was delivered or picked up. I need to find a percentage of delivered items from the total number of lines.

SALES_NBR | Total | Deliveryrate

1 = Delivered 0 = picked up from FULFILLMENT.

```
SELECT SALES_NBR, 
COUNT (ITEMS) as Total, 
SUM (case when FULFILLMENT = '1' then 1 else 0 end) as delivered,
(SELECT delivered/total) as Deliveryrate
FROM Invoice_table
WHERE STORE IN '0123'
And SALE_DATE >='2020-02-01'
And SALE_DATE <='2020-02-07'
Group By SALES_NBR, Deliveryrate;
```

My query executes but never finishes for some reason. Is there any easier way to do this? Fulfillment field does not contain any NULL values.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Be careful with integer division.

Comment: The desired results would be a table with the fields sales_nbr, total, deliveryrate (as a percentage) e.g. 12345, 1000, 0.10 (10%)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to find a percentage of delivered items from the total number of lines.

The simplest method is to use `avg()`:

```
select SALES_NBR, 
       avg(fulfillment) as delivered_ratio
from Invoice_table
where STORE = '0123' and
      SALE_DATE >='2020-02-01' and
      SALE_DATE <='2020-02-07'
group by SALES_NBR;
```

I'm not sure if the `group by` sales_nbr is needed.

Comment: This is what I needed.  I would've never thought to avg(fulfillment) since we're looking at 1's and 0's it works eh?

Comment: @BlueTorq . . . In some databases, you would need `avg(fulfillment * 1.0)` because they do integer averages.  But yes, this is a convenient shortcut in any database if you have a 0/1 flag column.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a "nice" query, you can use subqueries like this:

```
select
  qry.*,
  qry.delivered/qry.total as Deliveryrate
from (
  select 
    SALES_NBR, 
    count(ITEMS) as Total, 
    sum(case when FULFILLMENT = '1' then 1 else 0 end) as delivered
  from Invoice_table
  where STORE IN '0123'
    and SALE_DATE >='2020-02-01'
    and SALE_DATE <='2020-02-07'
  group by SALES_NBR
  ) qry;
```

But I think this one, even being ugglier, could perform faster:

```
  select 
    SALES_NBR, 
    count(ITEMS) as Total, 
    sum(case when FULFILLMENT = '1' then 1 else 0 end) as delivered,
    sum(case when FULFILLMENT = '1' then 1 else 0 end)/count(ITEMS) as Deliveryrate
  from Invoice_table
  where STORE IN '0123'
    and SALE_DATE >='2020-02-01'
    and SALE_DATE <='2020-02-07'
  group by SALES_NBR
```

Comment: It executed! Scanrate however is only returning 1's or 0's. Either the division is not happening correctly or its not formatted as a decimal to give us a percentage.  Do you know how to format the field Deliveryrate as a decimal?